# Is it possible to access nth depth element of an array by specifying an array of indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

### Update

Thank you all for your inputs, thanks to you I realize now I've made a seriously wrong assumption about JS. Actually, the code provided below works fine, if one modifies it:

```
...

  let currentPlaceInArray;
  for (let i = 0; i < position.length; i++) {
    let place = position[i];
    if (i + 1 === position.length) return currentPlaceInArray[place] = content; // Added this line now
    /***Explanation:
    Without this added line, the currentPlaceInArray variable is reassigned in the end
     to 'needle' in the present example. Thus, assigning it to something else (like
    currentPlaceInArray = ['updated']) will not have any effect on the array, because
    currentPlaceInArray is not assigned to it anymore, it's assigned to the string 'needle'
    ***/
    currentPlaceInArray = currentPlaceInArray ? currentPlaceInArray[place] : myArray[place]; 
  }
```

---

### Original problem

I have a large unstructured multidimensional array, I do not know how many nested arrays it has and they have different lengths, like in this simplified example:

```
var myArray =
[
  [
    [],[]
  ],
  [
    [],[],[],[]
  ],
  [
    [],
    [
      [
        ['needle']
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

I want to be able to update `'needle'` to something else. This would be possible by executing `myArray[2][1][0][0] = 'updated';`

I want to create a function which takes as parameters just 2 pieces of information: 1) the *string* to be written and 2) an *array* with the position of the array item to be updated. In the above case of `myArray`, it would be called thus: `changeNeedle('updated', [2, 1, 0, 0])`.

<del>However, I can't assign a variable to an *array key*, just to its *value*. If it was possible to assign a variable to the array *key*, I could just update that variable with the current position (i.e., `var currentPosition` would be `myArray[x]`, and `currentPosition[y]` would then be `myArray[x][y]`)</del> [**Update**: it's the exact opposite, assigning a variable to an array will point exactly to that array, so `currentPosition[y] === myArray[x][y]`]. Like so:

```
function changeNeedle(content, position) {
  /***
  content: a string
  position: an array, with the position of the item in myArray to be updated
  ***/

  let currentPlaceInArray;
  for (let i = 0; i < position.length; i++) {
    let place = position[i];
    currentPlaceInArray = currentPlaceInArray ? currentPlaceInArray[place] : myArray[place]; 
  }
  currentPlaceInArray = content;
}
```

Is it possible to implement this `changeNeedle` function without using `eval`, [window.Function()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!) or [adding a prototype to an array](http://jsfiddle.net/6r2t81w8/1/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first it looked like Chase's answer was kind of right (using recursion), but it seems you want your code to follow **only** the path provided to the function.

If you are **certain** of the position of the element you want to change, you can still use a recursive approach:

#### Pure JS recursive solution

```js
var myArray = [
  [
    [],
    []
  ],
  [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
  ],
  [
    [],
    [
      [
        ['needle']
      ]
    ]
  ]
];

function changeNeedle(arr, content, position) {

  // removes first element of position and assign to curPos
  let curPos = position.shift();

  // optional: throw error if position has nothing
  // it will throw an undefined error anyway, so it might be a good idea
  if (!arr[curPos])
    throw new Error("Nothing in specified position");

  if (!position.length) {
    // finished iterating through positions, so populate it
    arr[curPos] = content;
  } else {
    // passes the new level array and remaining position steps
    changeNeedle(arr[curPos], content, position);
  }

}

// alters the specified position
changeNeedle(myArray, 'I just got changed', [2, 1, 0, 0]);

console.log(myArray);
```

However, if you want to **search** for the element that corresponds to the content, you **still** have to iterate through **every** element.

Comment: Oh, wow, it was right in front of my face all of this time! I didn't know JS accepted `myArray[1,2,3,4]` as valid syntax! Thank you so much! I thought I'd have to use `myArray[1][2][3][4]`

Comment: No, it doesn't, I think! I think it's not throwing an error... but it's not really working the way you want. If you try accessing `myArray[2, 1, 0, 0]` it will only access `myArray[0]`. That's because it's interpreting the commas as [comma operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), so it returns only the last statement. (I'm really not using it this way in my solution, in case you got that impression from reading it. I really am iterating through the elements of the `position` array!)

Comment: Of course!X) I should be sleeping... Now I got why your recursion works, obviously because you're passing the nested array as the argument for the recursion

Comment: Can I ask you to rephrase the post title? Maybe something along the lines of "Is it possible to access nth depth element of an array by specifying an array of indexes?". I only say that because the impression I got from your title is that you were looking for [**Symbol wrappers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Symbol_wrapper_objects_as_property_keys), which do allow us to use objects or arrays as keys of an object. Pretty interesting concept, also, but not applicable as a solution to your particular problem, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to consider the well-tested Lodash function [update](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#update) (or set, and so on). I think that's very close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does look just like what I want. I'll try to find out how Lodash implements in vanilla JS it because I didn't want to load a library just for this

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid importing a library, a array-specific solution with in-place updates would look something like:

```js
function changeNeedle(searchValue, replaceWith, inputArray=myArray) {
  inputArray.forEach((v, idx) => {
    if (v === searchValue) {
      inputArray[idx] = replaceWith;
    } else if (Array.isArray(v)) {
      changeNeedle(searchValue, replaceWith, v);
    }
  });
  return inputArray;
}
```

Then you can call `changeNeedle('needle', 'pickle', myArray);` and your `myArray` value will be mutated to change instances of `needle` to `pickle`.

Return value and `myArray` would then look like:

```
JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 4);
[
    [
        [],
        []
    ],
    [
        [],
        [],
        [],
        []
    ],
    [
        [],
        [
            [
                [
                    "pickle"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

---

**Update: Based on your reply, a non-recursive solution that follows the exact path of a known update.**

```js
function changeNeedle(newValue, atPositions = [0], mutateArray = myArray) {
  let target = mutateArray;
  atPositions.forEach((targetPos, idx) => {
    if (idx >= atPositions.length - 1) {
      target[targetPos] = newValue;
    } else {
        target = target[targetPos];
    }
  });
  return mutateArray;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/y0365dng/

Comment: Thank you! But I think this solution is looping through all items of the array. I wanted to avoid this and go directly to the `['needle']` array by calling as argument the position `[2,1,0,0]` (instead of searching through all arrays (thousands of them))

Comment: Ah, got it. Understood, and you are correct. I added a direct manipulation viersion that doesn't require recursion if your other solution does not end up working out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! You're right, this solves it perfectly. You made me realize that I made a mistake previously. My above `changeNeedle` function only didn't work because in the end the `currentPlaceInArray` variable is reassigned to a string (`'needle'`). It's very late and it's been a while since I coded in JS, I assumed it wasn't working because the variable assignment was cloning the list (creating a new list and pointing to it in memory instead) instead of pointing to the original list. Except it was, until I reassigned the variable to something else. Sorry for this

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't.

The simplest way to do this is to store the array which you are going to modify (`array = myArray[2][1][0]`) and the key (`index = 0`). Then you just need to make a regular assignment like `array[index] = value`.

You can consider the following implementation:

```js
function changeNeedle(value, keys) {
  let target = array;

  for (const i of keys.slice(0, -1)) {
    target = target[i];
  }

  target[keys[keys.length - 1]] = value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I store the array I want to modify? This is my original question. Continuing with my example: `var store = myArray[0]; store = [12]; console.log(myArray[0]) //outputs [[], []]`

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I still don't follow exactly how it's supposed to work. Could you maybe us a concrete example? (though I should note that this question has been answered already)